# Strong end to end typing Nestjs React Prisma

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nestjs, typing

I am building a WebApp, and I want it to me **automatically strong typed** depending on endpoints i've made.

At the moment I am using this stack

Backend:

- Server on NestJS (REST Api)
- Prisma as ORM
- Swagger(OpenAPI) as API documentation

Frontend:

- React
- [Orval package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/orval) to read the swagger file and get API types

What i have now is an auto-generated swagger doc.
It's working for the POST requests (thanks to DTOs), but not for the POST / GET responses.

If my responses could be filled automaticaly in my swagger, I could resolve the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Can somebody help me to find a way to **have strong typed backend and frontend**?

Don't hesitate to ask for further question.

Thanks a lot for your time ;)